# Keras network structure probelm, net infront of input

Tags: keras

I'm try to build a neural network,

```
main_input = Input(shape=(2, 360, 1))
```

Here is my code, but I found in Tensorboard that there are layers in parallel with my input, which should not be the case.

See picture below, before first add. Why is that thank you !

```
def reslayer(_input):
    x = BatchNormalization()(_input)
    x = Convolution2D(64, 1, 3, border_mode='same', dim_ordering='tf', activation='relu', init='he_normal')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(64, 1, 3, border_mode='same', dim_ordering='tf', activation='relu', init='he_normal')(x)
    z = add([_input, x])
return z

flow = Convolution2D(64, 1, 3, border_mode='same', dim_ordering='tf', init='he_normal')(main_input)
flow = LeakyReLU()(flow)
flow = reslayer(flow)
flow = reslayer(flow)
```

Tensorboard
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of your add operation. My guess is that this operation is getting badly displayed by tensorboard in the first step. Nevertheless the model should be doing, what you expect it to do.